# Processing a TIF file -- Convert this transform from ImageMagick to Java

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, ocr

I'm trying to pre-proecess a PDF into a TIF image for OCR. On the command line, I can accomplish this by converting the PDF to a TIF using the following ImageMagick command:

```
$ convert -density 300 /path/to/my/document.pdf -depth 8 -strip -background white -alpha off file.tiff
```

How could I get an equivalent result in Java? I can currently convert PDF to TIF using tess4j, but how can I rescale and pre-process the resulting tif? What libraries would allow me to do this quickly and easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Rather than trying to learn another image pre-processing library, I just used [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net) to warp the IM command line and then directly translated the command to the following:

```
    ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();

    IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
    op.addImage(imagePath);
    op.density(300);
    op.depth(8);
    op.strip();
    op.background("white");
    op.alpha("off");

    try {
        cmd.run(op);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IM4JavaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: oh ok nice make sure you dont trip on the cables